# Player not falling when it is not colliding with platform Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm making this 2D game in pygame and I have run with an issue were when I try to leap off a platform, my player will just float instead of fall https://gyazo.com/82e9029b230326f182067a9f4a3cc47c. I been trying to use true and false statements to make it work, but most of the time my player will not move at all also I have tried telling it if its not colliding with the platform and that dose not work to.

This is one of the things I have tried

```
for Platform in platforms:
        if not playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
            playerman.y -= playerman.speed
```

a demo of my game

```
import pygame
pygame.init()


# width and height of winddow
window = pygame.display.set_mode((700,500))


# window name
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")


#Player class
class Player:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.speed = 4
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


class Platform:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)


class Platform2:
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.color = color
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
    def draw(self):
        self.rect.topleft = (self.x,self.y)
        pygame.draw.rect(window,self.color,self.rect)

           
# Colors
white = (255,255,255)
green = (255,0,0)


# class's cordination, size, and color

#Player
playerman = Player(300,250,40,70,white)


#Platform
platform1 = Platform(0,460,800,40,white)
#The top platform
platform2 = Platform2(0,0,800,40,green)


# List's
platforms = [platform1]
platforms2 = [platform2]


# drawing things in main loop
def redraw():
    # background color
    window.fill((0,0,0))


    # drawing the player in main loop
    playerman.draw()


    # Drawing all the bottom platforms in the main loop
    for Platform in platforms:
        Platform.draw()


    # Drawining all the top platforms in the main loop
    for Platform2 in platforms2:
        Platform2.draw()


# Timer for player falling
#fps for the game
fps = 30
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
up = True
down = False
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

            
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px,py = playerman.x,playerman.y


    if down == False:
        for Platform in platforms2:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform):
                up = True

                
    if up:
        playerman.y += 10
        fall = False


    for Platform in platforms:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
            up = False


    if up == False and  keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
                down = True
                up = False

                
    if down:
        playerman.y -= 10
        playerman.direction = "tjump"
        fall = False


    for Platform in platforms2:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
            down = False
            playerman.direction = "uidle"

   
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
        for Platform in platforms:
            for Platform2 in platforms2:
                Platform.x += playerman.speed
                Platform2.x += playerman.speed

                    
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and px < 2000 - playerman.width + playerman.speed:
        for Platform in platforms:
            for Platform2 in platforms2:
                Platform.x -= playerman.speed
                Platform2.x -= playerman.speed
                

    redraw()
    pygame.display.update()
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get you right now, you want to stick the player when it reaches the platform. If the platform leaves, you want the player bounces again.

The problem in your code is that you don't set the player's status when the platform leaves. You set both `up` and `down` to `False` to stick the player when player reaches the bottom platform. If the bottom platform leaves out, to make player move, you need to set `down=True`. That's what I do in the `else` statement. By setting `down=True`, we need to make sure the player has reached the bottom platform. I use an extra boolean variable `reach_up` to do that.

```py
    # The bottom platform
    # The bottom has larger y value, so it's up direction
    for Platform in platforms:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
            up = False
            reach_up = True
        else:
            if reach_up:
                down = True
                reach_up = False
```

The example code is

```py
up = True
down = False

reach_up = False
reach_down = False

while run:
    clock.tick(fps)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    px,py = playerman.x,playerman.y

    if down == False:
        for Platform in platforms2:
            if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform):
                up = True

    if up == False and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        for Platform in platforms:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
                down = True

    if up:
        playerman.y += 10

    if down:
        playerman.y -= 10

    for Platform in platforms:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
            up = False
            reach_up = True
        else:
            if reach_up:
                down = True
                reach_up = False

    for Platform in platforms2:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(Platform.rect):
            down = False
            reach_down = True
        else:
            if reach_down:
                up = True
                reach_down = False

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and px > playerman.speed:
        for Platform in platforms:
            for Platform2 in platforms2:
                Platform.x += playerman.speed
                Platform2.x += playerman.speed


    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and px < 2000 - playerman.width + playerman.speed:
        for Platform in platforms:
            for Platform2 in platforms2:
                Platform.x -= playerman.speed
                Platform2.x -= playerman.speed


    redraw()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Back to your code:

1. The RGB value of green is `(0,128,0)` not `(255,0,0)`
2. What's the meaning of class `Platform2`? You can initialize platform2 like `platform2 = Platform(0,0,800,40,green)`.

Comment: I set the both on them to false because I want the player to be able to stick to the top, not just bounce back and forth.

Comment: @Windowman I edited my answer, could you check if I get you right now?